# Optional parameter dependency for a service

Tags: symfony

I know that i is possible to add optional service dependency for a service. The syntax is

```
arguments: [@?my_mailer]
```

But how do i add optional **parameter** dependency for a service?

```
arguments: [%my_parameter%]
```

I tried

```
arguments: [%?my_parameter%]
arguments: [?%my_parameter%]
```

But neither of them work, is this feature implemented in sf2?

Comment: What is the benefit of an optional parameter? Parameters are for varying your configuration between environments. You could just vary the configuration across your environments, but that wouldn't be as clean.

Answer (score 13):

From Symfony 2.4 you can use expression for this:

> arguments: ["@=container.hasParameter('some_param') ?
>   parameter('some_param') : 'default_value'"]

More at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language

Comment: Also, you can use arguments: ["@=parameter('some_param') ? parameter('some_param') : 'default_value'"]

Answer (score 8):

I think  that if you don't pass/set the parameter, Symfony will complain about the service dependency. You want to make the parameter optional so that it is not required to always set in the config.yml file. And you want to use that parameter whenever it is set.

There is my solution:

```
# src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    my_parameter:

services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        "%my_mailer.class%"
        arguments:    ["%my_parameter%"]
```

And then

```
# you-bundle-dir/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('you_bundle_ns');

    // This is for wkhtmltopdf configuration
    $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('my_parameter')->defaultNull()->end()
            ->end();

    // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
    // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
    // more information on that topic.

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

And then

```
# you-bundle-dir/DependencyInjection/YourBundleExtension.php

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.xml');


    $container->setParameter(
        'you_bundle_ns.your_parameter',
        isset($$config['you_bundle_ns']['your_parameter'])?$$config['you_bundle_ns']['your_parameter']:null
    );
}
```

You make the your parameter optional by giving default value to the '%parameter%'

Please let me know if you have better alternatives.

Comment: `$$config` a typo?

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to set a default value for a parameter? Like so:

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle\Services;

class BarService
{
    public function __construct($param = null)
    {
        // Your login
    }
}
```

and not injecting anything.

Comment: Symfony will throws ParameterNotFoundException!